# BufferedImage.setRGB() not updating

Tags: java

I am trying to do something simple. I have always had trouble getting Java GUIs working properly. I want the pixels to update when I write to them; but the `for` loop's drawing doesn't seem to be being drawn. What kind of update method do I need to call to get my `BufferedImage` to show up?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class DirectDrawDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        Frame frame = new Frame("Direct draw demo");
        BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(
                width, height, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        for (int x = 1; x < width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, rgbtoint(0, 255, 0));
        System.out.println(canvas.getRGB(0, 0) != canvas.getRGB(1, 0));
        panel.paint(canvas.getGraphics());
        panel.repaint();
        frame.pack();
    }
    static int rgbtoint(int red, int green, int blue) {
        int rgb = red;
        rgb = (rgb << 8) + green;
        rgb = (rgb << 8) + blue;
        return rgb;
    }
    static int rgbtored(int rgb) {
        return (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    }
    static int rgbtogreen(int rgb) {
        return (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    }
    static int rgbtoblue(int rgb) {
        return rgb & 0xFF;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you are doing is painting the components of your panels on your image, instead of the other way around.

You seem to think that the method `paint(Graphics g)` puts the contents of `g` on the window. It doesn't. What it does is draw things on `g`. And it shouldn't be called directly. The usual way it works is that you create your own class that inherits from `Panel` (or whatever component), and *override* its `paint()` method, adding the operations that paint stuff inside it, by calling drawing methods of the `Graphics` object you are passed. In this case, you'd probably call `g.drawImage(...)`.

When `repaint()` is called on the component, its `paint()` method will be called with the graphics that represents the window's "canvas" as its parameter, and whatever you added to `paint()` will be therefore drawn on it.

To learn more, start from [the Oracle turorial on drawing primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html), and when you understand how the `paint()` method works, move on to [drawing images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/).

Answer (score 2):

To expand off of RealSkeptic's answer, here is an example of overriding the `paintComponent` method to add your custom drawing.

```
public static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public MyPanel(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 1; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                canvas.setRGB(x, y, new Color(0, 255, 0).getRGB());
            }
        }
        g.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Direct draw demo");
    JPanel panel = new MyPanel(640, 480);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image]